# Questions regarding backkey press of Wp7 Phone Application

Tags: windows-phone-7

Question regarding state of pages while deactivation and activation of page,i save the datas for that  particular page alone.when i go back to previous page,by pressing back button,I am getting previous page which does not have data in it.To load the data in the previous page i need to get the instance of previous page ,is there anyway to get the instance of previous pages in Phone Application stack.,Other thing,is that On backkey Press,handling onbackkey press,by navigating to the new instance of the previous phone application page(what will happen to old instance of the previous pages).how to handle these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

You have asked some questions recently on page state. When an app is deactivated and activated again Windows phone 7.5 saves the page state. All that you need to do is to carefully handle the Page_Loaded and OnNavigatedTo events upon activation.

And if you want to override the back stack OnBackKeyPress, you can do so and navigate to any other page instance. But you should ensure you removed the back stack entry. otherwise causes many problems.(but this is not recommended)

```
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

Comment: And still if you have any confusion over the navigation and state maintainance, Join this [Windows phone chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17226/windows-phone-7-8)!!